# clang++ always generates empty profraw coverage reports

Tags: c++, code-coverage, clang++, llvm-clang

I'm trying to integrate coverage in C++ with clang 6 for the first time and have been following [this](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html) guide.

I successfully compiled the binary, generated a `.profraw` file and generated a `.profdata` file as described in steps 1, 2 and 3a. But when I try to create a line-oriented coverage report as described in 3b, I receive the following message:

```
error: build/debug/dane: Failed to load coverage: No coverage data found
```

Upon checking the `.profraw` file, I found it was empty. I tried changing my code a bit and running again but the generated `.profraw` was always empty.

My `main.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My `SConstruct` file:

```py
env = Environment(CXX='clang++', CXXFLAGS=['-Wall', '-g', '-O0'], LINKFLAGS=['-fprofile-instr-generate', '-fcoverage-mapping'])
env.Program(target='build/debug/dane', source=['src/main.cpp'])
```

Command line output:

```sh
➤ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
clang++ -o src/main.o -c -Wall -g -O0 src/main.cpp
clang++ -o build/debug/dane -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping src/main.o
scons: done building targets.
➤ build/debug/dane
Hello, World!
➤ llvm-profdata merge -sparse default.profraw -o default.profdata
➤ llvm-cov show build/debug/dane -instr-profile=default.profdata
error: build/debug/dane: Failed to load coverage: No coverage data found
```

I expected the `default.profraw` file to hold meaningful coverage results, and have no clue why it's empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally solved it.
At first I gave the `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` flags as `CXXFLAGS`, but it didn't work, and so I understood that these were linker flags and moved them to the `LINKFLAGS` (which resulted in this frustrated post).
Apparently, these flags need to appear both as compilation and linker flags in order for the whole thing to work.
I also tried checking if you can distribute the flags between the compiler and the linker but that didn't succeed.